# How to pass a variable value to HTML using Java and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, lombok

I am new both to Spring Boot and Thymeleaf, and want to pass the value of a variable defined in the Java code to the HTML page. I searched the Web, but probably, I have overseen something important. I try to do it with the following code:

`Favorite.java`:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Favorite {

    private String id;
    private String target;

    public Favorite(final String id, final String target) {
        setId(id);
        setTarget(this.target);
    }
}
```

`PortalController.java`:

```
public class PortalController {

    private final List<Favorite> myFavorites = new ArrayList<>();

    @ModelAttribute("myFavorites")
    public List<Favorite> myFavorites() {

    if (myFavorites.size() == 0) {
        myFavorites.add(new Favorite("ZEMPLOYEE_WORKTIME_ZWD_ESS_ABW", "ABC"));
        myFavorites.add(new Favorite("ZEMPLOYEE_WORKTIME_CATS", "DEF"));
        myFavorites.add(new Favorite("ZEMPLOYEE_WORKTIME_PEP_WISH_PLAN", "XYZ"));
    }
    return myFavorites;
}
```

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="de" xml:lang="de">
<head>
    […]
</head>
<body>
    […]
        <ul>
            <div th:switch="${not #lists.isEmpty(myFavorites)}">
                <div th:case="true">
                    <div th:each="myFavorite : ${myFavorites}">
                        <li>
                            <td th:text="${myFavorite.id}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${myFavorite.task}"></td>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div th:case="*">
                        Nothing to show!
                </div>

            </div>
        </ul>
        […]
```

I get the "Nothing to show!" text, which means that `myFavorites` is empty. What do I miss or what did I misunderstood about this?

**Edit:**

I modified the `PortalController` after reading [The @ModelAttribute in Depth](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation#depth) to this:

```
public class PortalController {

private final List<Favorite> myFavorites = new ArrayList<>();
private final Map<String, List<Favorite>> favoritesMap = new HashMap<>();

@RequestMapping(value = "/getMyFavorites", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@ModelAttribute("myFavorites") final List<Favorite> favorites,
        final BindingResult result, final ModelMap model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) return "error";

    model.addAttribute("myFavorites", favorites);

    favoritesMap.put(favorites.toString(), favorites);

    return "favoritesView";
}

@ModelAttribute
public void getMyFavorites(final Model model) {

    if (myFavorites.size() == 0) {
        myFavorites.add(new Favorite("ZEMPLOYEE_WORKTIME_ZWD_ESS_ABW", "ABC"));
        […]
        }
        model.addAttribute("myFavorites", myFavorites);
}
```

Unfortunately, there is still something missing or misunderstood by me so that the Web page returns still "Nothing to show!".

**Edit 2:**

This is the current state I have after reading the documentation requested here:

`PortalController.java`:

```
public class PortalController {

private final List<Favorite> myFavorites = new ArrayList<>();

@RequestMapping(value = "/getMyFavorites", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String submit(@ModelAttribute("myFavorite") final List<Favorite> favorites,
        final BindingResult result, final ModelMap model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) return "error";

    model.addAttribute("myFavorites", favorites);

    return "favoritesView";
}

@ModelAttribute
public void getMyFavorites(final Model model) {

    if (myFavorites.size() == 0) {
        myFavorites.add(new Favorite("ZEMPLOYEE_WORKTIME_ZWD_ESS_ABW", "ABC"));
        […]
    }
    model.addAttribute("myFavorites", myFavorites);
}
```

`index.html`:

```
                        <ul>
                        <div th:switch="${not #lists.isEmpty(myFavorite)}">
                            <div th:case="true">
                                <div th:each="myFavorite : ${myFavorites}">
                                    <li>
                                        <td th:text="${myFavorite.id}"></td>
                                        <td th:text="${myFavorite.task}"></td>
                                    </li>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div th:case="false">
                                Nothing to show!
                            </div>
                        </ul>
```

But I still get "Nothing to show!", as `${myFavorites}` is empty.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-crud-thymeleaf

Comment: Havn't used Thymeleaf, but what happens if you remove the switch and just print ${myFavorites}?

Comment: Try it when you remove the `th:utext`. When I did it exactly like you with the `th:utext` I got an array with object references back which was shown.

Comment: @Kennet, you get just what you typed in: `print ${myFavorites}`. And @CodeMatrix, how could I remove `th:utext`? It's not used anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) @ModelAttribute should be used with @RequestMapping. You can find a more detailed description of how this annotation works [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-and-the-modelattribute-annotation).

Also for showing a table you can change your thymeleaf code to:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> id</th>
            <th> target</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:if="${myFavorites.empty}">
            <td colspan="2"> No Info </td>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="myFavorite: ${myFavorites}">
            <td><span th:text="${myFavorite.id}"> ID</span></td>
            <td><span th:text="${myFavorite.target}"> Target</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for this information! I made some modifications to the code, but still cannot pass the value to HTML. Perhaps, what I am doing wrong is to pass a class (`List<Favorite>`) to HTML instead of text only.

Comment: Look, currently, you use POST with favorites param. It means that when you will do a request the request body will be mapped to the favorites param. If it will be empty it will show nothing on view or print some error. You can try to change the request method to GET or just use @GetMapping("/getMyFavorites") and change  the line: model.addAttribute("myFavorites", someCreateListMethod());

Comment: RK_DEV, what about the `someCreateListMethod()`?

Comment: @Sae1962 just populate the list you want to show on view: `public List<Favorite> someMethod() { return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Favorite(), new Favorite))} ` or etc.